# Pressing one key registers as two separate keys

Tags: keyboard, keys

My Delete key registers and delete and slash

When I did `xev` and pressed Delete the following is shown

```
    root 0x7a6, subw 0x0, time 607462, (196,131), root:(368,295),
    state 0x0, keycode 106 (keysym 0xffaf, KP_Divide), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x7a6, subw 0x0, time 607624, (196,131), root:(368,295),
    state 0x0, keycode 119 (keysym 0xffff, Delete), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7f) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x7a6, subw 0x0, time 607635, (196,131), root:(368,295),
    state 0x0, keycode 106 (keysym 0xffaf, KP_Divide), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When I did `sudo showkey` and pressed delete the following is shown

```
^[[3~/keycode 111 press
keycode  98 press
keycode 111 release
keycode  98 release
```

Comment: Your keyboard seems to be faulty. You may try the same from a live Ubuntu session (by booting from Ubuntu installation media). Probably you spilled liquid on your keyboard and your Del key is close to (numeric keypad) `/` key ("KP_Divide"), and pressing one of these keys triggers the other.

Comment: But it is working fine in Windows 11